# Import Contacts into Company Directory in G Suite

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I have a .csv file of contacts that I exported from my personal gmail.com account. I want to import them into the company directory into new G Suite account. Importing them into a personal contact list was done with these instructions: https://superuser.com/questions/1274257/ but I cannot find a way to import them into the company-wide directory.

The company-wide directory is viewed by users at `Contact -> Directory` while logged into their personal account.

When I am logged in as administrator (at least I think I am) the `More v` menu item is grey and not clickable.  That is the menu item where I would expect to find an import menu item.

These are external contacts.  I want the small number of users on my G Suite account to all share our client contact emails and phone numbers.  I want to allow anyone to update the contact list and have everyone see the updates immediately.  I found a plugin to do this.

Comment: Michael, please read the description for the g-suite tag you've used the past two questions. Your questions are about the function of a Web Application, and therefore ought to be asked in the Web Apps StackExchange site. Also, your previous question was solved via a simple web search, and this one is too.

Comment: Regarding: "solved via a simple web search".  I beg to differ.  I have not found an answer to this question.  The previous question was not covered by a web search because there were no hits on how to migrate a subset of contacts.

Comment: I will be happy to migrate it, but it does not have a migrate feature.  If a mod can move it I would appreciate it.

Comment: The question can be moved by the community once enough votes have been cast to do so. Hold tight.

Comment: I've been assuming these are external contacts but you have not actually specified. Are they internal or external? If they are external Google has some specific rules about them: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1628009?hl=en